# How to get No extension file type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want get file type but my file noting extension in C#,Asp.net.

I want get file type from  downloaded file with `webClient.DownloadFile`.

Can trace file?

Can understand downloaded file is pdf or no?

Comment: Please edit your question so it makes more sense - at the moment it's too hard to understand, and we need to understand it in order to answer it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. Can you give a full example, detailing paths and filenames?

Comment: Please make your question clear so that you can get required help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\a.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
    string pdfText = r.ReadToEnd();
    Regex rx1 = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
    MatchCollection matches = rx1.Matches(pdfText);
    MessageBox.Show("The PDF file has " + matches.Count.ToString() + " page(s).";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute way to get the file type of a file with no extension.

Some file types, such as EXE, have a header that you could check. Other files, such as text files, could probably be detecting using some sort of heuristic that looks for only text characters. But still other files would not be identifiable.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the extension beforehand it's possible, otherwise you'd have to be familiar with the file's structure.  If all you're doing is downloading a pdf without the .pdf extension, rename your file [something].pdf when you download it and you'll be able to access it as a regular pdf.

Answer (score 0):

There are some links where same question has been asked . I hope it helps

https://superuser.com/questions/435224/how-do-i-find-out-the-file-type-without-an-extension

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/16c34850-8799-4a8b-8702-2f59d96e79c1

http://www.troublefixers.com/open-files-without-any-valid-file-extension/

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/812692-open-file-without-knowing-extension